# How to reply with an image with discord bot

Tags: rust, discord

I'm new to rust and as a practice project I'm building a bot using Serenity to handle the interactions with Discord. The bot should be able to reply to a message with an image. I can get the bot to post the image on the channel using CreateMessage like this:

```rust
let f = [(&tokio::fs::File::open("image.png").await?, "image.png")];
return match msg.channel_id.send_message(&context.http, |m| {
    m.content(replied_message.author);
    m.files(f);
    return m;
}).await {
    Ok(_) => Ok(()),
    Err(why) => Err(CommandError::from(why)),
};
```

Unfortunately this method doesn't work with reply, which wants a content that implements std::fmt::Display. I could use MessageBuilder, but it constructs a string and I don't know how to add the image to that, unless I add an URL. The image is an image::DynamicImage instance and serving it from another service is unpractical to say the least.

How can I use `message.reply_ping(&context.http, &reply)` to send an image?

Comment: It would be helpful to mention you're using the `serenity` crate to interact with Discord.

Comment: Definitely. I edited the question to add the mention, since I apparently forgot to add it in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `send_message()` approach like in your existing code, with some small additions.

`CreateMessage` has a `reference_message()` method you can use to set the message to reply to. And it has the `allowed_mentions()` method to configure pings:

```rust
match msg
    .channel_id
    .send_message(&context.http, |m| {
        // Reply to the given message
        m.reference_message(&replied_message);

        // Ping the replied user
        m.allowed_mentions(|am| {
            am.replied_user(true);
            am
        });


        // Attach image
        m.files(f);
        
        m
    })
    .await
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! As a follow up question, is there a better way to include the image in the response than writing it to a disk and then reading it to tokio file and adding it with `m.files()`?

Comment: @PanssariMureke you can pass in an array of `(&[u8], &str)` to `files()` instead, where `&[u8]` is the image data, and `&str` is the image filename.

Comment: So essentially AttachmentType File tuple. Got it working beautifully like that by writing the image to a buffer in png format. Thank you again!